# How can I retrieve the execution status of parallel triggered child jobs to a pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a pipeline script that executes child jobs in parallel.

Say I have 5 data (a,b,c,d,e) that has to be executed on 3 jobs (J1, J2, J3)

My pipeline script is in the below format

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  def index = i 
  branches["branch${i}"] = {
    build job: 'SampleJob', parameters: [
      string(name: 'param1', value:'${data}'),
      string(name:'dummy', value: "${index}")]
  }
}
parallel branches

My problem is, say the execution is happening on Job 1 with the data 1,2,3,4,5 and if the data 3 execution is failed on Job 1 then the data 3 execution should be stopped there itself and should not happen on the subsequent parallel execution on Jobs 2 and 3.

Is there any way that I can read the execution status of parallelly execution job status on the Pipeline script so that I can restrict data 3 execution to block in Jobs 2 and 3.

I am quite blocked here for a long time. Hoping for a solution from my community. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `result` property of object returned from the `build` step.

This was already asked and [has an answer over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961436/1824868).  Additionally, this is hinted at in the [official build step documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) in the description for the `propagate` parameter ("use the `result` property of the return value as needed").  I haven't tested it as I don't have a test Jenkins instance available right now, but based on those two pieces of information it looks like something like this should do the trick:

```
def b = build('my-job-name', wait: true)

def r = b.result
```